# Restore and evaluate a Tensorflow model

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am already saving this model during the training, but I am having a hard time to load it and evaluate it.

I tried some different approaches but I wasn't able to load the saved model and evaluate it to get its prediction over some test sample which is an image file.

Can anyone help with that? as I saw it not seems to be so hard but I am miss anything to do it right.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 128
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH = 50000
VALIDATION_SIZE = 10000
WIDTH = 128
HEIGHT = 64
CHANNELS = 3
CLASSES = 10
NUMBERS = 4


def inference(inputs):

    with tf.variable_scope("conv_pool_1"):
        kernel = tf.get_variable(name="kernel",
                                 shape=[5, 5, 3, 48],
                                 initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.05),
                                 dtype=tf.float32)
        biases = tf.get_variable(name="biases",
                                 shape=[48],
                                 initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.),
                                 dtype=tf.float32)
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input=inputs,
                            filter=kernel,
                            strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                            padding="SAME")
        conv_bias = tf.nn.bias_add(value=conv,
                                   bias=biases,
                                   name="add_biases")
        relu = tf.nn.relu(conv_bias)
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool(value=relu,
                              ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                              strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                              padding="SAME",
                              name="pooling")

    with tf.variable_scope("conv_pool_2"):
        kernel = tf.get_variable(name="kernel",
                                 shape=[5, 5, 48, 64],
                                 initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.05),
                                 dtype=tf.float32)
        biases = tf.get_variable(name="biases",
                                 shape=[64],
                                 initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.),
                                 dtype=tf.float32)
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input=pool,
                            filter=kernel,
                            strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                            padding="SAME")
        conv_bias = tf.nn.bias_add(value=conv,
                                   bias=biases,
                                   name="add_biases")
        relu = tf.nn.relu(conv_bias)
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool(value=relu,
                              ksize=[1, 2, 1, 1],
                              strides=[1, 2, 1, 1],
                              padding="SAME",
                              name="pooling")
    with tf.variable_scope("conv_pool_3"):
        kernel = tf.get_variable(name="kernel",
                                 shape=[5, 5, 64, 128],
                                 initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.05),
                                 dtype=tf.float32)
        biases = tf.get_variable(name="biases",
                                 shape=[128],
                                 initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.),
                                 dtype=tf.float32)
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input=pool,
                            filter=kernel,
                            strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                            padding="SAME")
        conv_bias = tf.nn.bias_add(value=conv,
                                   bias=biases,
                                   name="add_biases")
        relu = tf.nn.relu(conv_bias)
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool(value=relu,
                              ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                              strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                              padding="SAME",
                              name="pooling")
    reshape = tf.reshape(pool,
                         shape=[BATCH_SIZE, -1],
                         name="reshape")
    dims = reshape.get_shape().as_list()[-1]
    with tf.variable_scope("fully_conn"):
        weights = tf.get_variable(name="weights",
                                  shape=[dims, 2048],
                                  initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.05),
                                  dtype=tf.float32)
        biases = tf.get_variable(name="biases",
                                 shape=[2048],
                                 initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.),
                                 dtype=tf.float32)
        output = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(x=reshape,
                                 weights=weights,
                                 biases=biases)
        conn = tf.nn.relu(output)
    with tf.variable_scope("output"):
        weights = tf.get_variable(name="weights",
                                  shape=[2048, NUMBERS * CLASSES],
                                  initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.05),
                                  dtype=tf.float32)
        biases = tf.get_variable(name="biases",
                                 shape=[NUMBERS * CLASSES],
                                 initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.),
                                 dtype=tf.float32)
        logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(x=conn,
                                 weights=weights,
                                 biases=biases)
        reshape = tf.reshape(logits, shape=[BATCH_SIZE, NUMBERS, CLASSES])
    return reshape


def loss(logits, labels):
    cross_entropy_per_number = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy_per_number)
    tf.add_to_collection("loss", cross_entropy)
    return cross_entropy


def evaluation(logits, labels):
    prediction = tf.argmax(logits, 2)
    actual = tf.argmax(labels, 2)
    equal = tf.equal(prediction, actual)
    # equal = tf.reduce_all(equal, 1)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(equal, tf.float32), name="accuracy")
    return accuracy


def train(loss, learning_rate=0.00001):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
    return train_op
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you saving it? Have you tried:
(for saving)

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver.save(sess, 'my-model')
```

(for loading)

```
sess = tf.Session()
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my-model.meta')
new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

The official reference for this: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops/exporting_and_importing_meta_graphs (or substitute a release number such as `r0.12` for `master` in the URL).

Answer (score 0):

Now I am loading it correctly now

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model/model.ckpt.meta')

init = tf.group(tf.initialize_all_variables(),
                tf.initialize_local_variables())
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True))

saver.restore(sess, 'model/model.ckpt')
```

Now I am trying to get the prediction I think that is something like that, but I don't know how I will get the variables from the model which I created before in order to get its prediction:

```
prediction=tf.argmax(y_conv,1)
prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: [imvalue],keep_prob: 1.0}, session=sess)
```